# locationURI of "New"Menu Item

Tags: eclipse

I want to know locationURI of "New" MenuItem of Eclipse plugin. For example, for "Configure" Menu the locationURI is "org.eclipse.ui.projectConfigure". My task is to make popup submenu item adding "New" menu. So I need to know menubarpath for New Menu. If someone knows, please share source code to me.

Answer (score 0):

The id is `org.eclipse.ui.file.newQuickMenu` according to the code which creates it in `WorkbenchActionBuilder`.

The New menu is handled specially and normal ways of contributing to it may not work. The normal way to add to the New menu is by using the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point.

Comment: <action
                class="myproject.Action1"
                icon="icons/delete.gif"
                id="myproject.matrix.action1"
                label="Hello"
                menubarPath="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards/additions"
                  enablesFor="+" >
          </action>
       
        </extension> This is my code but it still not show"Hello"submenuItem in "New"menu.How to do it?

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` is an extension point not a menu path. `org.eclipse.ui.file.newQuickMenu` is the menu path, but adding to this probably won't work. You need to use the new wizards extension point to add to the New menu.

Comment: I used newWizard for adding new SubMenuItem in New Menu.At that time,that new submenuitem is visible in all parts.I want that new added submenuItem is visible only when I right click on my project type either in package explorer or project explorer.